# POST base64 image to web API using Swift 4

Tags: swift, rest, api, base64, ocr

I'm trying to make a call to the OCR.space API by uploading a base 64 image but I keep getting this response:

> Not a valid base64 image. The accepted base64 image format is 'data:image/;base64,'

I've checked the image many times to make sure it's encoded properly in base 64 format. Am I setting up the URLRequest properly?

Here is the code:

```
func extractTextFromImage(_ image: CGImage) {

    let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: image)
    let imageData = bitmapRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.jpeg, properties: [:])! as Data
    let imageString = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithCarriageReturn)

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image")!

    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("6ea787d56088957", forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")

    var parameters = ["base64image": [ "content_type": "image/jpeg", "base64": imageString]]

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
        let theJSONText = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("JSON string = \(theJSONText)")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print("ERROR: Could not convert dictionary to JSON")
        return
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("6ea787d56088957", forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")

    let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        if let response = response {
            print("RESPONSE: ", response)
        } else {
            print("ERROR: No response")
        }

        if let error = error {
            print("ERROR: ", error)
        } else {
            print("No error")
        }

        do {

            let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: Any]

            for (key, value) in dictionary {
                print("Key: ", key)
                print("Value: ", value)
            }

            if let parsedResults = dictionary["ParsedResults"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                if let parsedResult = parsedResults.first {
                    if let parsedText = parsedResult["ParsedText"] as? String {
                        print("PARSED TEXT ", parsedText)
                    } else {
                        print("ERROR: Could not read parsedText")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("ERROR: Could not read first element of parsedResult")
                }
            } else {
                print("ERROR: Could not read parsedResult")
            }

        } catch let error {
            print("ERROR: Could not serialize jSON Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but perhaps you need to add a `Content-Type` header of `data:image/;base64,` ?

Comment: I tried that but now the error response is: "No file uploaded or URL or base64 provided"

Comment: where is `bodyData` coming from in this example? I don't see where it's defined.

Comment: Apologies, I must have missed that line when I copped the code from the project. I added it now near the 10th line. bodyData is simply the base64 image string with an added header

Comment: One thing I notice: You're encoding the image using the JPEG encoder, but you're specifying it as PNG in the `bodyData` prefix.

Comment: I updated the post to show the whole function. I'm still getting the "invalid base 64 image" error

Comment: did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

After alot of reading and searching, this is the code that I got to work:

```
    ///
    ///    Extracts the text from the given image by placing a call to the OCR.space web api
    ///
    func extractText(from image: CGImage) {

        let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: image)
        let imageData = bitmapRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.png, properties: [:])! as Data

        let url = URL(string: "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image")!

        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let boundary = "--------69-69-69-69-69"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("6ea787d56088957", forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")
        request.httpBody = createBody(parameters: nil, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData, boundary: boundary)

        let task = session.synchronousDataTask(urlrequest: request)
        let data = task.0
        let error = task.2

        if data == nil {
            print("ERROR: No response from OCR.space api call")
            return
        }

        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR: ", error!)
            return
        }

        do {
            let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: Any]

            if let parsedResults = dictionary["ParsedResults"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                if let parsedResult = parsedResults.first {
                    if let text = parsedResult["ParsedText"] as? String {
                        parsedText = text
                        return
                    } else {
                        print("ERROR: Could not read parsedText")
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    print("ERROR: Could not read first element of parsedResult")
                    return
                }
            } else {
                print("ERROR: Could not read parsedResult")
                return
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("ERROR: Could not serialize jSON Data into dictionary: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    ///
    ///    Creates a the body of the url request using the given parameters
    ///
    private func createBody(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: Data, boundary: String) -> Data {
        var body = Data();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            }
        }

        let filename = "image.jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append(imageDataKey)
        body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        return body
    }
```